# How to make a file path work that starts with root path(slash)?

Tags: html

I am working on some static pages whose file names start with root slash. e.g. /css/style.css

The reason is, the files are part of CMS but I need to work on the static pages on my local machine without the CMS.

Is there a way to make my page work with /css/style.css without removing the root slash?

I am using Mac.

Sorry for not being clear. I am not getting the correct term for it.

Comment: /css/style.css will point to the root of your webdirectory and then look in css directory. I do not now the behaviour if you would save the page for offline viewing, but I figure your browser will sort this out on saving. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Kaj Toet. This helped me understand the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move files to `/`(root dir) or install any webserver

Answer (score 0):

You can try a

```
<base href="/" />
```

The other option is to use relative paths, such as

```
../../css/style.css
```

Comment: Where should I include <base href="/" />?

Comment: `<base>` tags go in the `<head>` block of html pages.